# How to match '-' literally inside [..] in regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match a '-' inside a [..] block using regular expressions in python, but, I am not sure how to make that happen, since '-' denotes ranges in that block.

Edit: my failing regex:

```
regex = re.compile("^[0-9+-*/]+$")
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html):

> If you want to include a `']'` or a `'-'` inside a set, precede it with a backslash, or place it as the first character.

Answer (score 6):

Just place it at the beginning of the `[]` (character class):

```
regex = re.compile("^[-0-9+*/]+$")
```

**Why does it work?**

When you place the hyphen at the beginning of the character class, most regular expression engines are intelligent enough to realize that you mean a literal hyphen (since you can't indicate a range without an beginning).

Comment: Your text says to put the hyphen at the start of the set, but your example puts it at the end. Both styles appear to work, but since the documentation only mentions the start I would avoid putting it at the end.

Comment: Good catch. I originally wrote my answer to mention both the start and end, but I edited it once I double-checked the documentation. I forgot to edit the example to reflect that. Thanks!